# Error embedding .tex file (diagram) inside another .tex file: `Error: I do not know the key 'tikz/rectangle split'`

Tags: tikz-pgf, input

In learning how to create higher quality diagrams, I came across the `tikz` package and specifically this [example tutorial web page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/class-diagram/) (www.texample.net/tikz/examples/class-diagram/).

I verbatim took the script provided there, and I am able to compile it to make the diagram as shown in the link.

However, I then tried to embed that diagram into my main document using `\input` and I could not get it to work.

---

## Full Code Details

### Parent file (attempting to embed the `RDB_diagram_shell.tex` file):

```
% Load necessary packages

\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley} % I like this theme better
\usecolortheme{wolverine} % This gives the orange colorscheme
\usepackage{standalone} % I was trying to use this package to embed diagram files within here.
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title Slide
\title{Blah}
\author{Mike Williamson}

\begin{document}
%%%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{RDB Tables Example}

\input{RDB_diagram_shell}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### `RDB_diagram_shell.tex`:

```
% DB Layout diagram

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
%\coordinate (origin) at (50,50);

\node (Order) [facttable, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] {
    \textbf{ORDER}
    \nodepart{second}
        order\_num (PK) \\
        customer\_ID (FK) \\
        store\_ID (FK) \\
        clerk\_ID (FK) \\
        date        
};
\node (AuxNodeTop) [text width=0.5cm, above=of Order, shift={(0,-1.5cm)}] {};
\node (Store) [dimtable, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, left=of AuxNodeTop] {
    \textbf{STORE}
    \nodepart{second}
        store\_ID (PK) \\
        store\_name \\
        address \\
        district \\
        floor\_type 
};

\node (Clerk) [dimtable, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, right=of AuxNodeTop] {
    \textbf{CLERK}
    \nodepart{second}
        clerk\_ID (PK) \\
        clerk\_name \\
        clerk\_grade
};

\node (Customer) [dimtable, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, below=of Order, shift={(0,1cm)}] {
    \textbf{CUSTOMER}
    \nodepart{second}
        customer\_ID (PK) \\
        customer\_name \\
        purchase\_profile \\
        credit\_profile \\
        address
};

\draw[rightarrow] (Store.south) -- ++(-0.5, 0) -| (Order.west);
\draw[leftarrow] (Clerk.south) -- ++(0.5, 0) -| (Order.east);
\draw[uparrow] (Customer.north) -| (Order.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

That is the entirety of both scripts.

## Error

I am receiving the following error:

```
...DB_diagram.tex:20: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/rectangle split' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you mis-spelled it.
```

It seems to suggest I cannot have the words `rectangle` and `split` separated by a space character. (Note: these key words **only exist** within the file being embedded, which compiles fine when compiled alone.) But then why does it work when I make the file alone, without embedding it?

---

Again, to reiterate:

- I ***am able to*** compile the diagram when I compile it alone. But I ***am not able to*** compile it when it is embedded in a small, shell file.

  - Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

Some of the commentors below wanted to see the actual file. The Tex files are both given above, so I presume the commentor wanted to see the rendered file from the smaller Tex file which I could compile.  Here it is:

[image: Rendered RBD Diagram Shell file]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When you are saying you can compile the file when it is embedded in a small shell file, what is there in the preamble? I suspect the error goes away when you include `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}` in the preamble of your main document.

Comment: @marmot Thanks! That helped... somewhat.  Now instead of the error given above, I received `Package PGP Math Error: Unknown function 'of' (in 'of Item').` This is coming from the line `\node (AuxNode01) [text width=4cm, below=of Item] {};`. Now it seems that line cannot properly be identified.  But, can you tell me why this `shapes.multipart` helped?  And also, how could I have found that documentation? I didn't see anything anywhere about multipart (until now, since I know what to search for.) Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and @marmot , the pre-amble is *exactly* what I wrote in the question. That code, plus the code in the provided link, are the entirety of what I wrote. (I had a more complex `.tex` file at first, but I pared it down to make the example easier.)

Comment: The linked TeX code has it's own preamble. I assume you do not input the full thing, but only the `tikzpicture`, right? The error you get is because you do not load `positioning`. Just try adding `\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}` to your preamble. But I cannot really help you because I don't have a crystal ball that allows me to see your shell.

Comment: @marmot I have now placed the **entirety** of both of the scripts on the question.

Comment: Sorry, not quite. You can certainly not compile `RDB_diagram_shell.tex`, can you?  And what happens if you add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}` to your main preamble?

Comment: You say that RDB_diagram_shell.tex compiles fine when being compiled alone.  Can you show us the file you used to make that claim?  And as long as we're paring things down, can you remove the `\draw` commands and three of the nodes, but still get the error?  Ideally, you'd end up with a parent file that has the contents of RDB_diagram_shell.tex, but fails when you `\input{RDB_diagram_shell}`.

Comment: You definitely can't compile any file which starts `\begin{tikzpicture}` on its own. Regardless. You must wrap it in a `document` and provide a preamble. It is that preamble which makes the difference. That preamble sets up things like `rectangle split` and the `of` syntax - things which are not defined if you load `tikz` on its own.

Comment: @marmot Yes, I **am** able to compile RDB_diagram_shell.tex as is.  I have already added the `\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}` to the pre-amble, as I had shown in the main script above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have more issues with your document examples:

- the package `standalone` from "standalone" file with your images strip out its preamble, `\begin{document}` and`\end{document}` and import to main document only image code. consequently all packages and definitions in standalone are invisible to the main document.
- if `tikzpicture` contain some options append to it in square brackets, than the frame in main document had to have option `[fragile]`
- as solution of your problems you need add to main file complete preamble of the "standalone" file. so far it seems that you add only a part of its preamble, consequently missing packages and style definitions cause reported errors.
- since your styles used in your "standalone" file are unknown to us, i reconstruct own styles (try to use mine, it seems that they are shorter and more consistent) and embedded it to `tikz` picture:

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Berkeley}       % I like this theme better
  \usecolortheme{wolverine} % This gives the orange colorscheme
  \usepackage{standalone}   % I was trying to use this package to embed diagram files within here.
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,      % <----
                  positioning,
                  shadows, 
                  shapes.multipart}  % <----

  \begin{document}
  %%%%
  \begin{frame}[fragile]          % <----
  \frametitle{RDB Tables Example}

  % for simplify tests i include the content of the "standalone" file here
      \begin{tikzpicture}[        % <----
  node distance = 5mm and 3mm,
     MPN/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Multi Part Node            % <----
                   rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                   draw, rounded corners,
                   fill=#1,
                   text=#2, font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.9}\selectfont,
                   text width=28mm, align=center, 
                   drop shadow},
     MPN/.default = blue!50/white,                          % <----
     arr/.style = {semithick, -{Triangle[open]}}            % <----
                          ]
  \node (Order) [MPN=green!30/black] {                      % <----
      \textbf{ORDER}
      \nodepart{second}
          order\_num (PK) \\
          customer\_ID (FK) \\
          store\_ID (FK) \\
          clerk\_ID (FK) \\
          date
                      };
  \node (Store) [MPN, above left=of Order.west] {           % <---- 
      \textbf{STORE}
      \nodepart{two}
          store\_ID (PK) \\
          store\_name \\
          address \\
          district \\
          floor\_type
                      };
  \node (Clerk) [MPN, above right=of Order.east] {          % <----
      \textbf{CLERK}
      \nodepart{two}
          clerk\_ID (PK) \\
          clerk\_name \\
          clerk\_grade
                      };
  \node (Customer) [MPN, below=of Order] {                  % <----
      \textbf{CUSTOMER}
      \nodepart{two}
          customer\_ID (PK) \\
          customer\_name \\
          purchase\_profile \\
          credit\_profile \\
          address
                      };
  \draw[arr] (Store) |- (Order);     % <----
  \draw[arr] (Clerk) |- (Order);     % <----
  \draw[arr] (Customer) -- (Order);  % <----
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

which gives

[image]

the same result you should obtain with

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Berkeley}       % I like this theme better
    \usecolortheme{wolverine} % This gives the orange colorscheme
    \usepackage{standalone}   % I was trying to use this package to embed diagram files within here.
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                    positioning,
                    shadows, shapes.multipart}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{RDB Tables Example}
    \input{RDB_diagram_shell}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

where `RDB_diagram_shell` is

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}   % diagram "RDB_diagram_shell".
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                    positioning,
                    shadows, shapes.multipart}

    \begin{document}
    % code of `tikzpicture` as is written in complete mwe above
    \end{document}
```